# React+Node have to use 2 seperate codebases/servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is the most basic question.

In every online example I see, to get a website running with NodeJS and React two seperate programs/servers are created. One runs on port 3000 and the other on 3001. Is this necessary?
If react is a frontend engine why does it have to run on a port or a server?

Im confused as to why they always use create-react-app which may be running on its own server im not sure.

I would like to create app.js import 'express' to handle requests and also import React on the same file, but I run into compilation errors, will this approach work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this necessary?

No, this isn't ever necessary and is only *typically* done in development.

> If react is a frontend engine why does it have to run on a port or a server?

Webpack (the thing *typically* bundling your React code for browser usage, similar tools are vite/snowpack) creates a server for live updates and errors so changes in your React automatically propagate to the UI.

This is *only* done during development and not in production. It's a convenience feature while developing the code.

> I would like to create app.js import 'express' to handle requests and also import React on the same file, but I run into compilation errors, will this approach work?

Frontend code usually has a build step where you run `npm run build` which runs `webpack --production` over your code (or esbuild or other similar tools). After this point all your frontend code is *typically* static files (.js .html .css etc) from which point you just serve them from static file storage (usually a CDN for faster load times in different geographies).

Comment: OK so it makes far more sense to do it this strange way with the call to make a proxy between 3000 and 3001 while developing because its lightning fast to update the webpage after writing new code?

Comment: @Keith correct, that's right

Comment: Worth mentioning it's about more than refreshing fast, fast-refresh (the library that does this for react on top of hot module replacement which comes from webpack's dev server) actually preserves current state (useState values) between "refreshes" enabling a much nicer experience when working on state-heavy stuff (like forms)

Comment: Hi, thanks for those answers. If someone wants to transfer their site onto the internet how would they organize it then? I thought I would investigate NextJS and GatsbyJS as possible solutions but neither of them compile :/